# Applying multiple filters to an ArrayList of Objects

Tags: java, filtering

This is my first question on StackOverflow after some lurking over the years. 
I should make clear I am not a very advanced programmer, and mostly create utility tools for work, please keep it simple.

I have a program that shows a view of 'OrderLine'. These OrderLines have 4 properties, packSize, repCode, productGroup & productType that need to be filtered on.

The different filter options are as follows:

```
String[] bulkNonBulk = new String[]{"Bulk", "Non Bulk", "Bulk Lubricant"};
String[] productGroup = new String[]{"BLK", "CUT", "ENG", "FRM", "GRS", "HYD", "IND", "MIS", "SS", "TNK", "TRA"};
String[] repCode = new String[]{"BJ", "BS1", "BS2", "FF", "HSE", "OFF", "PCH", "TMO", "TM"};
String[] packSize = new String[]{"1 Litre", "4 Litre", "5 Litre", "10 Litre", "20 Litre", "25 Litre", "60 Litre", "199 Litre", "200 Litre", "205 Litre", "208 Litre", "1000 Litre", "Litre"};
```

The user will have CheckBoxes that can be selected for each of these properties, and I need any orders that match the above filters to be displayed.

I.E. if a filter of Bulk, Non Bulk, Litre and BS1 are selected needs to return all orders that have those properties.

The problem I'm having is relating to the logic of setting these filters up. At the moment I have the following:

```
private void filterOrders()
{
    List<OrderLine> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for(OrderLine ol : orderListing)
    {
        boolean addOrderLine = false;
        if(ol.getOrderDate().before(currentEndDate) && 
                ol.getOrderDate().after(currentStartDate))
        {
            addOrderLine = true;
            for(CheckBoxFilter cbf : currentFilterList)
            {
                //ol.getFilterList simply returns a list of the filters.
                //cbf.getInternalName returns the name of the filter the CheckBox is associated with.
                if(!ol.getFilterList().toString().contains(cbf.getInternalName()))
                {
                    addOrderLine = false;
                }
            }
        }
        if(addOrderLine)
        {
            list.add(ol);
        }
    }

    filteredOrderLineList = list;
    for(OrderLine ooll : filteredOrderLineList)
    {
        System.out.println(ooll.toString());
    }
}
```

Take as an example The

```
OrderLine.getFilterList()
```

method returning the following String ArrayList: "Non Bulk, OFF, ENG, 20", that is productType, repCode, productGroup & packSize respectively. If for example the user has selected multiple productGroups I.E. 'ENG, HYD, IND', no products will ever get added to the orderList, due to the fact that when the String returned from the above code snippet is asked to see if it contains  the individual filter name

```
cbf.getInternalName()
```

It will return true for one of the filters:

```
ol.getFilterList().toString().contains(cbf.getInternalName()))

or ("Non Bulk", "OFF", "ENG", "20").contains("ENG)) //Above code with actual Strings
```

However all the others will return false, due to the fact that when for the for loop completes for the previous individual filter, the next filter has the name below for example of "HYD".

```
ol.getFilterList().toString().contains(cbf.getInternalName()))

or ("Non Bulk", "OFF", "ENG", "20").contains("HYD")) //Above code with actual Strings
```

Of course because we are still in the same OrderLine Loop and it returned true for the previous query, we want it added to the list.

I have spent 3 days looking at this, and for some reason I am having a mind block on it. I know it is probably a fairly obvious solution, however it is getting the combination of filters to work together that is the problem.

If you could perhaps advise where I am going wrong with the logic on this it would be really appreciated.

If you need any more information on the classes / methods used please say.

P.S. I have looked in quite a lot of detail for questions on filtering lists, however it is more the logic of the filtering that I am looking for help on here. I realise there is information on using Streams and Lambda expressions, and if you would like to add information on that please feel free, however the underlying issue I'm having is with the logic and not the semantics as such.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code should probably change as below.

```
private void filterOrders()
{
    List<OrderLine> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for(OrderLine ol : orderListing)
    {
        boolean addOrderLine = false; // need to ensure items outside date range not added      
        if(ol.getOrderDate().before(currentEndDate) && 
              ol.getOrderDate().after(currentStartDate))
        {
             addOrderLine = true;
             for(CheckBoxFilter cbf : currentFilterList)
             {
                 //ol.getFilterList simply returns a list of the filters.
                 //cbf.getInternalName returns the name of the filter the CheckBox is associated with.
                 if(!ol.getFilterList().toString().contains(cbf.getInternalName()))
                {
                    addOrderLine = false;
                }
            }
        }
        if(addOrderLine)
        {
            list.add(ol);
        }
    }

    filteredOrderLineList = list;
    for(OrderLine ooll : filteredOrderLineList)
    {
        System.out.println(ooll.toString());
    }
}
```

### Update

The code has been asked to deliver if for any 'column' the orderline matches any of the set filters.

There is a missing grouping - each filter needs to be associated directly with a column, and then testing if any is set can be done

In pseudo code :-

```
for each item
   if in date
       for each column
           columnOk = false
           if column not filtered 
               then columnOk = true
           else

              for each filter on single column
                  if selected
                       columnOk = true

           if columnOk = false then reject
       if not rejected then add to list
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that was an oversight on my part. I have updated my question to be more specific with the problem I'm having which I didn't do in the first case.